# Assign Java reference to null won't affect the other object

Tags: java, object, reference

I have two string arrays, and one is assign by the other. Why I assign one of them to null won't affect the other? As the console output , they both have the same address. Is't not the same with c++? here is my code:

```
String []  bikes = new String[5];
String [] largerBikes = new String[bikes.length + 5];
bikes = largerBikes;
System.out.println(bikes);
System.out.println(largerBikes);
largerBikes = null;
System.out.println(bikes);
System.out.println(largerBikes);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: " Is't not the same with c++? " No. But this wouldn't happen in C++ either.

Comment: Unlike in C++, a variable in Java is a **reference** to an object, it's not the value of the object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> they both have the same address

No, they both point to the same address.

When you assign null to `largerBikes` you have merely set that variable (reference to actual array content) to null, not the content it points to.

`bikes` and `largerBikes` are separated from each other. `bikes` variable itself is stored separately from the `largerBikes` variable.

When you write `bikes = largerBikes` you have following situation:

[image]

But then when you write `largerBikes = null` you will just clear that single reference to the array:

[image]